# Trying to populate a form select with user information

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-form

Im trying to populate a forms select with user information from a database using larval.  I'm also using the form helper from laravelcollective.com.

Here is the code in the controller

```
public function create()
{

    $users = DB::table('users')->select('id', 'firstname as name')->get();

    return view('messages.create')->with('users');
}
```

Even though I am using querybuilder here, it works.  It returns the id and the firstname field as name.  So I dont think this is the problem.

Here is the code in the create.blade.php file

```
{{ Form::select('user', [$users], null) }}
```

With this code, I get a working page that doesn't have anything in the select box.

With this code

```
{!! Form::select('user_id', $users, null) !!}
```

I get an Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error

And with this code

```
{!! Form::select('user_id', [$users], null) !!}
```

I get a working page with nothing in the select box.

So I tried any different things and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array as second parameter:

```
{!! Form::select('user_id', $users, null) !!}
```

You can use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method which is very convenient way to build an array for `Form::select`

```
$users = User::pluck('firstname', 'id');
```

Or you could do this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->pluck('firstname', 'id');
```